# appending data in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var data = {
    formData : {
        vendor:    'test',
        extension: 'test2'
    }

}
```

I am trying to append a serialized array to fromData.

How would I go about doing this.

Would I push it?

```
data.formData({ inputs.serializeArray() });
```

Thanks!

Comment: `data.formData.inputs = value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.serializeArray` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) returns an array of objects of the form `{name: '...', value: '...'}`.

So you would have to iterate over the array and add each object to your `formData` object:

```
$.each(inputs.serializeArray(), function(i, obj) {
    data.formData[obj.name] = obj.value;
});
```